# How do I add a button to a slash command response in discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

How do I add a button to a message that my bot sends after a slash command is executed. (I'm running python 3.8).

I want to type '/image prompt' in discord and have my program check if the user has accepted the terms and conditions. If they haven't then the bot will send a message with a button attached to agree to the terms.

I would prefer not to use classes if possible.

```
import discord, threading, asyncio, discord.ext.commands, discord.app_commands, datetime, pathlib, hashlib, random, json, os
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import app_commands, Interaction#, ButtonStyle, Button
from discord.ui import Button, ButtonStyle
from typing import Optional

TOKEN='my token'
intents=discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content=True
client=commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', case_insensitive=True, intents=intents)
tree=client.tree

#other commands here

@client.event #add button function
async def on_button_click(interaction):
    if interaction.component.custom_id=='Confirm image':
        #add user to the list of users who have accepted the terms and conditions

@tree.command(name="image", description="Generates an image using stable diffusion", guild=discord.Object(id=1140580736412434472))
async def image(ctx, prompt: str, replyprivately: Optional[bool]):
    print(f'{ctx.user.name} added {prompt} to the queue.')
    import json
    with open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), 'botconfig', 'imageusers.json'), 'r') as f:
        file=json.load(f)
    if ctx.user.id not in file:
        ctx.response.send_message("Please agree to T&Cs") #I want to add a button to this message

client.run(TOKEN)
```

I have tried using
`ctx.respond.send_message('message', components=[Button(style=ButtonStyle.primary, label='I understand', custom_id="Confirm image")])` but i get errors like this

````
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\tjgor\anaconda3\envs\ldm\lib\site-packages\discord\app_commands\commands.py", line 828, in _do_call
    return await self._callback(interaction, **params)  # type: ignore
  File "E:\Documents\coding\Python\stable diffusion discord bot\stable-diffusion-main\mainbot.py", line 109, in image
    ctx.response.send_message("Some of the models we use have the ability to generate NSFW images. Please confirm that you understand", components=[Button(style=ButtonStyle.primary, label='I understand', custom_id="Confirm image")])
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'style'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\tjgor\anaconda3\envs\ldm\lib\site-packages\discord\app_commands\tree.py", line 1248, in _call
    await command._invoke_with_namespace(interaction, namespace)
  File "C:\Users\tjgor\anaconda3\envs\ldm\lib\site-packages\discord\app_commands\commands.py", line 853, in _invoke_with_namespace
    return await self._do_call(interaction, transformed_values)
  File "C:\Users\tjgor\anaconda3\envs\ldm\lib\site-packages\discord\app_commands\commands.py", line 842, in _do_call
    raise CommandInvokeError(self, e) from e
discord.app_commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command 'image' raised an exception: TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'style'```
````

Answer (score 1):

You can **attach a discord button** to a message by sending it with the `view=` param.

First, you need to **create the Class** for the `discord.ui.View` object:

```py
# Define a simple Button View class
class Confirm(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.value = None

    # When the button is pressed, set the inner value to `True` and
    # stop the View from listening to more input.
    # We also send the user an ephemeral message that we're confirming their choice.
    @discord.ui.button(label='Confirm', style=discord.ButtonStyle.green)
    async def confirm(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button):
        await interaction.response.send_message('Confirming', ephemeral=True)
        self.value = True
        self.stop()

    # This one is similar to the confirmation button except sets the inner value to `False`
    @discord.ui.button(label='Cancel', style=discord.ButtonStyle.grey)
    async def cancel(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button):
        await interaction.response.send_message('Cancelling', ephemeral=True)
        self.value = False
        self.stop()
```

And now you can send the class attached to a message:

```py
await interaction.response.send_message("Message with buttons", view=Confirm())
```

---

By the way, the event `on_button_click` doesn't exist in discord.py. You can see all registered events (regarding interactions) here: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#interactions