# discord.py - How do I add buttons to a slash command response?

Tags: python, discord.py

me again
I want to know how to add buttons to a slash command response, I've looked around on the internet and none of them helped. Does anyone know how to make some? Thanks :)

edit: I tried this: [How do I add a button to a slash command response in discord.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77019082/how-do-i-add-a-button-to-a-slash-command-response-in-discord-py) but now I'm getting an error:

`TypeError: asdf() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'self', 'interaction', and 'button'`

code:

```
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.value = None

@bot.tree.command(name="tester", description="tester")
async def hello(ctx: discord.Interaction):
    await ctx.response.send_message("tester", view=asdf())

@discord.ui.button(label='test', style=discord.ButtonStyle.grey)
async def asdf(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button):
    await interaction.response.send_message('workie', ephemeral=True)
    print("yes")
```

Comment: i did try this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77019082/how-do-i-add-a-button-to-a-slash-command-response-in-discord-py) but it didn't work.

Comment: Please provide [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for your problem with the error traceback you've received.

Comment: it didn't have any errors... there is a view=confirm() in there

Comment: check edits, please, i just got an error

Comment: First of all your syntax is incorrect and it should be `await ctx.response.send_message("tester", view=Confirm())` assuming your `class`'s name is `Confirm` as shown in referenced answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> edit: I tried this: How do I add a button to a slash command response in discord.py but now I'm getting an error:

Did you actually try the code? It works perfectly!

###### Simple example of custom View:

```py
#Custom View Class
class MyView(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    #setting up button (you can add multiple such)
    @discord.ui.button(label='test', style=discord.ButtonStyle.grey)
    async def asdf(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button):
        # on interaction
        await interaction.response.send_message('workie', ephemeral=True)
        print("yes")

@bot.tree.command(name="tester", description="tester")
async def hello(ctx: discord.Interaction):
    # add the view to a message
    await ctx.response.send_message("tester", view=MyView())
```

If you don't want classes or *don't know how to use classes* you can go with code similar to:

```py
button = discord.Button(label="Click me!", style=discord.ButtonStyle.grey)
async def button_callback(interaction:discord.Interaction):
    await interaction.response.send_message("workie!",ephemeral=True)
view = discord.View()
view.add_item(button)


@bot.tree.command(name="tester", description="tester")
async def hello(ctx: discord.Interaction):
    await ctx.response.send_message("tester", view=view)
```